# Ant EXEC failing to run bash script

Tags: ant, exec

I am trying to use ant to run a bash script.

Ive found that the exec directive is the tool for the job

I created a bash script test.sh
and in my ant target i added:

```
<project basedir=".">
    <property name="temp.deployment.dir" value="temp_deployment_dir"/>
    <property name="temp.dir" value="temp_upload_dir"/>
    <property name="src.dir" value="www"/>
    <property name="js.dir" value="${src.dir}/public/js"/>
    <property name="css.dir" value="${src.dir}/public/css"/>
    <property name="img.dir" value="${src.dir}/public/images/"/>
    <target name="clean">
            <delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="update-statics">
            <mkdir dir="${temp.dir}"/>
            <!--TODO: add statics in -->
    </target>
    <target name="deploy">
            <mkdir dir="${$temp.deployment.dir}"/>
            <copy todir="${temp.deployment.dir}">
                    <fileset dir="${src.dir}"/>
            </copy>
            <exec executable="bash" newenvironment="false" dir=".">
                <arg value="cmd_update.sh"/>
            </exec>
     </target>
</project>
```

I get build successful when i run it, but the test.sh is never run.

I have googled and searched for what I could be doing wrong but because there is no error I am having trouble debugging it. Does anyone know the proper usage of the exec directive or if there is something I am clearly doing wrong. From What I can tell I am doing it the same as ever other example of exec I have found.

Comment: Is bash on your PATH? Is cmd_update.sh in the current working directory?

Comment: @user508771 some additional information would be helpful, especially output from running `ant deploy. 

See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Answer (score 4):

If you have the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) in your Bash script, and your script is executable, you don't need to include `bash` as the command. (I am, of course, assuming Linux, Unix, or Mac).

```
<exec executable="${path.to.command}/cmd_update.sh"
    failonerror="true"
    osfamily="unix"/>
```

Always set `failonerror` to true and always set `osfamily`.

There maybe other things you want to set like the property where *STDOUT* and *STDERR* are stored. You can also pass parameters via the `<arg value>` sub-tasks.

I would not use the `searchpath` parameter since that could be a security hole.

Comment: This helped me solve a problem that was similar. Thanks, this saved me lots of time.

Answer (score 1):

First things first - I usually cringe when I see an exec, it's usually something smelly.
You want to set failonerror to 'true' when using exec, and make sure your script is exiting with a proper return code where appropriate.

You also don't need to call bash, you can call the script directly - make sure it's executable.

The output of ant -v would be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<exec executable="**/bin/**bash" newenvironment="false" dir=".">  
    <arg value="cmd_update.sh"/>             
</exec>
```