# Ant: How to apply multiple commands to the same output file?

Tags: ant

I have some image files that need processing as part of an Ant build process.

The processing is two-step. Some of the input files are JPEGs and the conversion process has to first convert them to PNG, and then run a separate program on them to convert the PNGs to ETC1 textures.

How may this be accomplished in Ant? As far as I can tell the <apply> task only allows a single command to run.

Comment: That may be one way. But the .pngs mustn't hang around, they are just intermediate files. The dependency is between input .jpg and output .etc1, and I don't want a zillion .pngs hanging around just so a .jpg->.png->.etc1 chain can work.

Comment: Hey could my "command" be a bash script??

Comment: delete them after the two apply tasks? Yes, your command could also be a script. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188901/ant-exec-failing-to-run-bash-script

Comment: @ReubenScratton: yes, it can be a bash script. Only make sure to set execution permission on the file and execute it with `./my_bash_script.sh` or `/path/to/my_bash_script.sh` or put it on system PATH.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it to work with a bash script - very simple solution. Shame I can't embed the bash commands within the build.xml but it's good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, this can be trivially done with a simple bash script running the 2 commands.